# Does Bot Framework store any data in Azure if I replace the default bot storage with my own custom storage?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I have a client that is very jealous about her data and she asked me to replace the default bot storage of my bot with a custom storage that saves all the data in an on-premises database.

If I replace the storage, will the bot framework save permanently any conversation data in any other place? (let's say, somewhere in Azure) That's something my client would like to avoid for security concerns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Saving and loading of all `session` data is handled in the `ChatConnector`'s `getData()` and `saveData()` unless you provided your own via `settings.storage`. In non-emulator real-life scenarios it will go to https://state.botframework.com/v3/botstate/...

The bot framework doesn't store anything else, I believe. I explored this exact question very recently. Take a look:

- http://www.pveller.com/smarter-conversations-part-3-breadcrumbs/
- http://www.pveller.com/smarter-conversations-part-4-transcript/

I had to read the source (many times actually) to trace the inner workings of the Bot Framework and I didn't see anything that would make me think that there's another persistence somewhere.

You are probably better off asking on the official support channel to confirm and assure your client but I think you're good.

As to how *reasonable* it is... companies do far more crazier things for all kinds of reasons :) By the way, will you also use Microsoft's LUIS for NLU? Does your client have similar concerns about all incoming messages going through that service? It's a deep rabbit hole. I think of engagement (vs. back office automation) bots as very much cloud-native. Not easy to shield yourself from it and yet benefit from all the new tech built for it.